# Component directives encapsulation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-component, custom-element

I'd like to know what would be the idiomatic way of encapsulating AngularJS component directives (conceptually and implementation-wise) given that their state may be mutated through their attributes or their controller's public interface.

A simple concrete example could be a `<spinner>` component that has a `step` attribute which may only be numeric. What to do when `step="non-numeric-value"`?

HTML gives us many examples where invalid property/attribute values are silently ignored (HTML validators may complain though), but I couldn't find any explicitly written standard to follow in the [Web Components specification](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/) to reflect in the Angular's world nor that I found anything on the subject in the AngularJS docs.

Regarding the implementation specifics in AngularJS, independently of what should conceptually happen, would using custom getters/setters on the controller for every bindings be the right way to apply encapsulation? Perhaps using the `$onChanges` hook of components would be better?

E.g. with custom getters/setters

```
module.component('spinner', {
    bindings: {
      step: '<'
    },
    controller: Spinner,
    template: '{{$ctrl.step}}'
  });

  function Spinner() {
    this.step = 1;
  }

  Spinner.prototype = {
    constructor: Spinner,

    get step() {
      return this._step;
    },

    set step(value) {
      if (!isNumeric(value)) {
        //Issue a warning? Throw error?
        return;
      }

      this._step = value;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Not sure if this is usefull. More code, less perfomance - just to perform some check that is usefull only during development.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov In a very large component tree, it could become hard to spot errors due to erroneous configurations or silently broken contracts. I've always been an advocate of the fail-fast principle in other contexts and I think it should probably apply to components too. I'm not sure if performance impacts would be noticeable for common scenarios, but it would depend on the nature of the checks.

Comment: Assuming that it is actually a behaviour that you expect from your component, I recommend using `$onChanges` for two reasons; First: to keep the binding behaviour in the angularjs way, try not to run much far from the root that is the digest cycle; Second: Using `$onChanges` you guarantee that when changes happen on your bindings you are able to validate the consistency again emiting exceptions, logs or whatever you like to notify that rules have been broken on your code so that you can go fix it. However, as @PetrAveryanov has told, it might not be necessary keeping this level of consistency.